# How do you describe the set solutions to $y = x + 1 + \frac{2}{x+3}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}$]?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

> How do you describe the set of solutions to
> $$y = x + 1 + \frac{2}{x+3}$$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}$] ?

---

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] := \{ a + b\sqrt{-2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is an integral domain and
I have also shown that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is a Euclidean domain so for every $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ theres exists $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ such that $x = qy + r$.

How do you use this fact to help you find solutions to the equation? Do I need to show $\frac{2}{x+3}$ has to be in form $a + b\sqrt{-2}$ ?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: `$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] := \{ a + b\sqrt{-2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$` is both easier to type and looks better: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}] := \{ a + b\sqrt{-2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We need $x+3\mid 2$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$. In particular we have $N(x+3)\mid N(2)=4$. Let $x=a+b\sqrt{-2}$. Then the norm is given by $N(x)=a^2+2b^2$. Hence we have $((a+3)^2+2b^2 )\mid 4$. This has only very few integer solutions in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: No, the sum is quickly is bigger than $4$. Take any example, like $b=2$. Then $2b^2=8$ and adding a square is ... well. Of course then $(a+3)^2+8$ does not divide $4$.